# How can I add multiple data to one column according to the specific data in another column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I do not know how insert the Host_Account_Manager called Adam at once according to Brooklyn in neighbourhood_group. How could I do it ? I do not want to copy and paste it because there are tons of records in the excel sheet.

```
neighbourhood_group   Host_Account_Manager

Brooklyn              Adam
Manhattan
Manhattan
Brooklyn              Adam
Brooklyn              Adam
```

Comment: There is a lot missing in this question. It is unclear if you want to do this as an excel formula or an SQL output. Can you describe the whole problem in more detail along with what you have tried? From what you have posted so far, the answer could be to put `=IF([@[neighbourhood_group]]="Brooklyn","Adam","")` as an Excel formula in Host_Account_Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a list of names and groups (for instance in column `A:D`), you can INDEX/MATCH them:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$3,MATCH($A$1:$A$6,$D$1:$D$3,0)),"")`

[image]